# Pandas Multi Index, Hierarchical Index

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, multi-index

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv('<https://gist.githubusercontent.com/justmarkham/19241df07db2b93283fbb0cfe9c572f9/raw/f70931bd9f25c560b330f017f6933073c442c7ed/stocks.csv>')
df2=df.set_index(['Symbol','Date'])
df2.sort_index(inplace=True)
print(df2)

s = df.loc[ ('AAPL','2016-10-05') :('MSFT','2016-10-03') ]
print(s)
```

My DataFrame is per below:

```
                    Close    Volume
Symbol    Date                        
AAPL   2016-10-03  112.52  21701800
       2016-10-04  113.00  29736800
       2016-10-05  113.05  21453100
CSCO   2016-10-03   31.50  14070500
       2016-10-04   31.35  18460400
       2016-10-05   31.59  11808600
MSFT   2016-10-03   57.42  19189500
       2016-10-04   57.24  20085900
       2016-10-05   57.64  16726400
```

I have below 2 questions.

1) My requirement is to get the data from the last row in AAPL (i.e. date = '2016-10-05') till the first row in MSFT (i.e. date = '2016-10-03'.

I wrote the below code

```
df.loc [('AAPL','2016-10-05'):('MSFT','2016-10-03')]
```

However, I am getting the error: AssertionError: Start slice bound is non-scalar.

**Note: My above code is inline to the documentation example: In[44] from [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html).

2) In the 2nd case, I want the data from the middle row (i.e. date of 2016-10-04) of CSCO till the end of dataframe (that is all the rows of MSFT) and only the column: Volume.

Appreciate if you point me where I went wrong.

Thank you
Srikanth

Comment: There is typo proecessing `df2`, not `df`, need `s = df2.loc[ ('AAPL','2016-10-05') :('MSFT','2016-10-03') ]
print(s)`

Comment: @jezrael  
My apologies for wasting others time. Yes its a typo.